# I have a bug in my code. tell me please

Tags: c++

I'm trying to search for the presence of '..' in a string that represents a file path on a POSIX system. I'm using std::string.find(".."), and it seems to be finding the correct index, but is not evaluating correctly in boolean expressions. Please give suggestion how i complete this?

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    std::string a = "abcd";

    int apos = a.find( ".." );

    bool test1 = a.find( ".." ) >= 0;
    bool test2 = apos >= 0;

    if ( test1 ) {
        printf( "TEST1 FAILED: %ld >= 0!\n", a.find( ".." ) );
    }
    if ( test2 ) {
        printf( "TEST2 FAILED %d >= 0!\n", apos );
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a debugger for a reason: please use it!

Comment: I get a warning: "warning: comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true".

Answer (score 2):

It's not a matter of testing vs. 0 but against `std::string::npos`. Look at the documentation on [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find):

```
bool found = a.find('..') != std::string::npos;
```